# String concatenation in jdo query

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I am trying to do a query that does a `like` search on concatenated results.
In sql it would look like this:
`WHERE firstname + ' ' + lastname LIKE '%namesearch%'`

When trying this in jdo I do this:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(User.class);
Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
args.put("search", search);
q.setFilter("(user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname).indexOf(:search) >= 0");
q.executeWithMap(args);
```

However doing this results in a parsing exception.

`Portion of expression could not be parsed: (:search) >= 0`

Is it possible to do concatenated expression searches in `JDO` like this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I see is that you forgot to call `q.declareParameters("String search")`

Comment: Sorry, that's not it. `user.firstname.indexOf(:search) >= 0` works fine